# What is the correlation between $2$ Brownian motions at time $t_1$ and $t_2?$ Assume that they are jointly normal with correlation $\rho.$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

The following is an interview question taken from Mark Joshi et al. Quant job interview book.

> Question: What is the correlation between $2$ Brownian motions at time $t_1$ and $t_2?$ Assume that they are jointly normal with correlation $\rho.$

Initially I thought that we are asked to find correlation between $B_{t_1}$ and $B_{t_2}$ where $(B_t)_t$ is a Brownian motion. 
By using correlation formula, we have the correlation is 
$$\frac{Cov(B_{t_1},B_{t_2})}{\sigma_{B_{t_1}}\sigma_{B_{t_2}}} = \frac{\min(t_1,t_2)}{\sqrt{t_1}\sqrt{t_2}}.$$

However, the answer given is 
$$\rho \sqrt{\frac{\min(t_1,t_2)}{\max(t_1,t_2)}}.$$

I think I do not understand the question.

It would be good if someone can clarify the question for me.

Comment: You have two DIFFERENT Brownian motions.